# Marshall abstract class without its type definition

Tags: xsd, abstract-class, jaxb2

I try to achive the opposite of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087809/marshalling-arraylist-of-abstract-class-in-jaxb). I have an abstract class, but I do not  want the abstract class' type and tag to be outputted. So I need an output, which basically looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dokument ausgabe="ausgabe_test.doc" vorlage="vorlage_test.dot">
    <marke typ="text" name="test">
        <text>This is a test</text>
    </marke>
</dokument>
```

rather than

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dokument ausgabe="ausgabe_test.doc" vorlage="vorlage_test.dot">
    <marke typ="text" name="test">
        <inhalt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="text">
            <text>This is a test</text>
        </inhalt>
    </marke>
</dokument>
```

`Text` is inherited from the abstract class `Inhalt`.

My current (generated) schema is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="dokument" type="dokument"/>

  <xs:complexType name="dokument">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="marke" type="marke" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="vorlage" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ausgabe" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="marke">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="inhalt" type="inhalt"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="typ" type="markenTyp" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="inhalt" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="style" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="text">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="inhalt">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="markenTyp">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="text"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="tabelle"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="liste"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You did not include a schema, so it's a bit tricky to comment. In principle, you cannot serialise an abstract element or type as that's illegal...

Comment: My schema is generated, so I thought it would not be that interesting. I added it to my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the schema you have supplied, I would say the following: remember that inheritance of complex types in XML Schema is not *exactly* the same as you would expect in Java.

In your schema/object model, you have a type `inhalt` and a type `text` that inherits from it. `inhalt` is abstract. So far, so good. The difference comes in the *usage* of the types. You assign the type `inhalt` to an **element** called `inhalt`. That means only the element `inhalt` can appear there, not `text`, and the xsi:type override is necessary to indicate which subtype is being used (the parser cannot guess it).

You can achieve what you want to achieve if you use a **substitution group** in addition to the sub-typing, this will allow the element `text` to appear. Refactor the schema as follows:

1. Create a global element with name "inhalt", and type "inhalt" (make the type name upper case if you think this is confusing)
2. Create a global element with name "text" and type "text". Set the substitution group attribute of "text" to "inhalt".
3. Replace the local element reference in "marke" with a reference to the global element.

For reference, here is the new model of `marke`:

```
<xs:element name="inhalt" type="inhalt"/>
<xs:element name="text" type="text" substitutionGroup="inhalt"/>
<xs:complexType name="marke">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="inhalt"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="typ" type="markenTyp" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

After this, `text` can appear inside `marke`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Though, I still need to read about substitution groups to understand them.